Select records with earliest date only if followed by another type of record
I have a table where I'm trying to do the following:

If a claim has both a Claim Creation and Claim Creation Followup, then I want the earliest date for the Claim Creation Followup and do not care about the Claim Creation.

If the claim only has Claim Creation, then I want the earliest date for Claim Creation. I want all tasks that follow the Claim Creation/Followup since they are meant to be grouped with the Claim Creation/Followup.

If a claim that has either a Claim Creation/Claim Creation Followup that is followed by a different task, then the next Claim Creation/Claim Creation task should start the next iteration with a 1.  If a claim has multiple Claim Creation/Followup tasks without a different task immediately following then I only want the initial Claim Creation/Followup.


Code:
DECLARE @t TABLE
           (
               claimid int,
               taskname varchar(100),
               completedate datetime,
               tasknumber int
           )

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (123, 'Claim Creation', '01/01/2024', 455),
       (123, 'Incoming', '01/05/2024', 367),
       (123, 'Claim Creation', '02/01/2024', 455),
       (123, 'Incoming', '02/02/2024', 367),
       (234, 'Claim Creation', '03/24/2024', 455),
       (234, 'Claim Creation Followup', '03/25/2024', 566),
       (234, 'Claim Creation Followup', '03/26/2024', 566),
       (234, 'Incoming', '03/28/2024', 367),
       (224, 'Claim Creation Followup', '02/02/2024', 566),
       (224, 'Claim Creation Followup', '02/25/2024', 566)

The result should look like this:



ClaimID
Task
Date
TaskID
Rownum




123
Claim Creation
01/01/2024
455
1


123
Incoming
01/05/2024
367
2


123
Claim Creation
02/01/2024
455
1


123
Incoming
02/02/2024
367
2


234
Claim Creation Followup
03/25/2024
566
1


234
Incoming
03/28/2024
367
2


234
Claim Creation Followup
02/02/2024
566
1



My code:
select
    *,
    row_number()
        over(partition by claimnumber
             order by
                 case
                     when tasknumber = 566 then 1
                     when tasknumber = 455 then 2
                     else 3
                 end,
                 completedate asc) as rownum
from @t

My output:



ClaimId
Task
Completedate
TaskNumber
Rownum




123
Claim Creation
01/01/2024
455
1


123
Claim Creation
02/01/2024
455
2


123
Incoming
01/05/2024
367
3


123
Incoming
02/02/2024
367
4


224
Claim Creation Followup
02/02/2024
566
1


224
Claim Creation Followup
02/25/2024
566
2


234
Claim Creation Followup
03/25/2024
566
1


234
Claim Creation Followup
03/26/2024
566
2


234
Claim Creation
03/24/2024
455
3


234
Incoming
03/28/2024
367
4



I thought a window function might work. I feel I'm on the right track but I'm still not getting the results I'm looking for.

Note: Someone edited this and messed up the desired output.  The field headings should match those from My Output.

Sorry about that. Is it correct now?

Yes.  Thank you!

So this sounds like a variation of gaps-and-islands, where a "Claim Creation" sometimes defines the start of a new group within a ClaimId. The trick will be nailing down those conditions to something that can be coded. Would it be sufficient to define a "Claim Creation" as a new "Claim Creation" if the immediately preceding task is something other than "Claim Creation" ("Claim Creation Followup" or other task)? If not, what would be an exception? Once we have that defined, we can look for the "starting" task of interest.

Yes, that is one way to look at it.  If the preceding task is something other than "Claim Creation" or "Claim Creation Followup" then 'Claim Creation" is a new 'Claim Creation."  The only exception is if the first record is a 'Claim Creation' since nothing would be preceding it.

What about the sequences: (1) Claim-Creation, Claim-Creation-Followup, Claim-Creation. (2) Claim-Creation, Incoming, Claim-Creation-Followup, Claim-Creation. (3) Claim-Creation, Claim-Creation-Followup, Incoming, Claim-Creation-Followup, Claim-Creation. Would the second Claim-Creation in each sequence be considered *new" or a continuation of the prior claim. The logic needed would be much different if we can just look one row back or need to look at multiple rows in the history. One can use LAG() while the other may require a recursive CTE.

In the first sequence we only want Claim Creation Followup because we would take this over Claim Creation if there is no other task in between.  In the second sequence we want Claim Creation, Incoming.  In the third sequence we want Claim Creation Followup, Incoming.  The second Claim Creation in each sequence is only considered new if there is another status that follows, such as Incoming.  If the sequence is just Claim Creation, Claim Creation, Claim Creation Followup, Claim Creation Followup, Incoming then we would want the earliest Claim Creation Followup.

The idea behind this is I'm trying to find how long it takes between the first Claim Creation/Followup status and an Incoming Status.  They may create a half dozen Claim Creation/Followup statuses before they create an Incoming.  So if there are multiple Claim Creations in a row we want the earliest one.

Your last comment really changes the desired results. You don't really want a sequence or rows, you want to (for each group) select a first reference claim-creation or claim-creation-followup date plus the (next?) Incoming date, and then compare the two side-by-side. In that case, the final select should probably use conditional aggregation* to extract the reference date from the first following incoming date into separate columns.

I think the following will be close to what you need, but you may need to run it through a greater variety of test cases and tweak some of the logic.
This uses a variation of gap-and-islands logic to:

Sequence the source data by ClaimId.
Scan the data to identify gaps (start of each new group) as either (a) The first row in a partition, or (b) A claim-creation task that does not immediately follow another claim-creation or claim-creation-followup task.
Assign islands (group numbers) to all rows within each partition calculated as the running sum of the new-group flags.
Identify the sequence numbers of the first claim-creation and first claim-creation-followup within each group. (We will later use COALESCE() to prioritize the claim-creation-followup.)
Join the prior two intermediate results and filter the data to only include (a) the "selected" starting claim-creation or claim-creation-followup task (b) Any other task that follows.

DECLARE @CreationTaskNum INT = 455;
DECLARE @FollowUpTaskNum INT = 566;
  
WITH SequencedTasks AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClaimId ORDER BY CompleteDate) AS Seq
    FROM ClaimActivity
),
Gaps AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN (Seq = 1 OR (
                 TaskNumber = @CreationTaskNum
                 AND LAG(TaskNumber) OVER(PARTITION BY ClaimId ORDER BY Seq)
                     NOT IN (@CreationTaskNum, @FollowUpTaskNum)
             )) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NewGroup
    FROM SequencedTasks
),
Islands AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(NewGroup) OVER(PARTITION BY ClaimId ORDER BY Seq) AS GroupNum
    FROM Gaps
),
FirstClaimTasks AS (
    SELECT
        ClaimId,
        GroupNum,
        MIN(CASE WHEN TaskNumber = @CreationTaskNum THEN Seq END) AS FirstClaimSeq,
        MIN(CASE WHEN TaskNumber = @FollowupTaskNum THEN Seq END) AS FirstFollowupSeq
    FROM Islands
    GROUP BY ClaimId, GroupNum
)
SELECT
    F.ClaimId, I.Task, I.CompleteDate, I.TaskNumber, F.GroupNum,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY F.ClaimId, F.GroupNum ORDER BY I.Seq) AS RowNum
FROM FirstClaimTasks F
JOIN Islands I
    ON I.ClaimId = F.ClaimId
    AND I.GroupNum = F.GroupNum
    AND (
        I.Seq = COALESCE(F.FirstFollowupSeq, F.FirstClaimSeq)
        OR (
            I.Seq > COALESCE(F.FirstFollowupSeq, F.FirstClaimSeq)
            AND I.TaskNumber NOT IN (@CreationTaskNum, @FollowUpTaskNum)
    ))
ORDER BY F.ClaimId, F.GroupNum, I.Seq;

The TaskNumber = @CreationTaskNum check in the NewGroup might need to be TaskNumber IN (@CreationTaskNum, @FollowUpTaskNum).
Results:



ClaimId
Task
CompleteDate
TaskNumber
GroupNum
RowNum




123
Claim Creation
2024-01-01
455
1
1


123
Incoming
2024-01-05
367
1
2


123
Claim Creation
2024-02-01
455
2
1


123
Incoming
2024-02-02
367
2
2


224
Claim Creation Followup
2024-02-02
566
1
1


234
Claim Creation Followup
2024-03-25
566
1
1


234
Incoming
2024-03-28
367
1
2



Note that the above includes a ClaimId = 224 row not present in your desired results.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
If you really just want to select a reference claim data and an associated input date for comparison, you can change the final select to something like:
...
DECLARE @IncomingTaskNum INT = 367;

WITH ...
SELECT
    F.ClaimId, F.GroupNum,
    MIN(CASE WHEN I.Seq = COALESCE(F.FirstFollowupSeq, F.FirstClaimSeq)
        THEN I.CompleteDate END) AS ReferenceDate,
    MIN(CASE WHEN I.Seq > COALESCE(F.FirstFollowupSeq, F.FirstClaimSeq)
             AND I.TaskNumber = @IncomingTaskNum
        THEN I.CompleteDate END) AS IncomingDate
FROM FirstClaimTasks F
JOIN Islands I
    ON I.ClaimId = F.ClaimId
    AND I.GroupNum = F.GroupNum
GROUP BY F.ClaimId, F.GroupNum
ORDER BY F.ClaimId, F.GroupNum;

Results:



ClaimId
GroupNum
ReferenceDate
IncomingDate




123
1
2024-01-01
2024-01-05


123
2
2024-02-01
2024-02-02


224
1
2024-02-02
null


234
1
2024-03-25
2024-03-28



See this updated db<>fiddle for a demo.

So far this looks like it's working after changing the TaskNumber = (@CreationTaskNum) to TaskNumber In (@CreationTaskNum, @FollowUpTaskNum).  I don't believe I want the ClaimId = 224 in the final results.  I'll keep testing.

Your updated code is confusing me.  The original code is perfect except I don't want the claimid = 224 which does not have another status following it.

To eliminate the 224 case, you can add MAX(Seq) AS LastSeq to the FirstClaimTasks CTE and then add the condition F.LastSeq > to COALESCE(F.FirstFollowupSeq, F.FirstClaimSeq) to the final select.

The updated code was to support your earlier "find how long it takes between the first Claim Creation/Followup status and an Incoming Status." comment. It gives you two dates on one row. You would then just need to calculate the difference.

Maybe I'm not doing it right but it's not removing that record. I added Max(seq) as LastSeq to FirstClaim Tasks. Then added this to the final select: And F.LastSeq > Coalesce(F.FirstFollowupSeq, F.FirstClaimSeq).

Try calculating MAX(CASE WHEN TaskNumber = @IncomingTaskNum THEN Seq END) AS LastIncomingSeq and filter F.LastIncomingSeq> COALESCE(F.FirstFollowupSeq, F.FirstClaimSeq).

That looks like it's working.  I'll work on the date calcs next. Thank you for your help.

Any chance you can get the dates with the same group number on one row?  I used the last select to remove the unwanted 224 case but I don't see how to apply your code to put it onto one line

I apparently do not understand what you are asking. My earlier "updated question" was addressing what you mentioned in an earlier comment, but that was apparently also not what you wanted. Why don't you update your question to show what you really want in your desired results with a clear description of all of the rules to be applied and sufficient sample data to show all possible scenarios.

I'm trying to take the result from your query and add one more step.  I need all the claim numbers within the same group to appear on one line.  ClaimNumber = 123 with GroupNum =1 should all appear on one line.  That way I can find the difference between the dates.

"... update your question to show what you really want in your desired results with a clear description of all of the rules to be applied and sufficient sample data to show all possible scenarios."
